# NSIS Installer with Windows Versions check

Tags: compiler-errors, windows-installer, nsis

I'm trying to compile this code

```
;Test App Install
;Mustermann GmbH
; V.0.1 05/21 KM
;--------------------------------

;Generate unicode installer
  Unicode True
;General

;Name and file
 Name "Windows check"
  OutFile "Windowscheck.exe"
  InstallDir "c:\install"
  ShowInstDetails show

;Request application privileges
RequestExecutionLevel admin
;--------------------------------
;Include UltraModernUI

  !include "UMUI.nsh"
;--------------------------------
;Include x64/x32 Driver InstallOptions

  !include x64.nsh

;--------------------------------
;Include PowerShell Support

  !include psexec.nsh

;--------------------------------
;Include Windows Version Check

!include WinVer.nsh



;Interface Settings

  !define UMUI_SKIN "Mustermann"

  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
  !define MUI_UNABORTWARNING

;  !define UMUI_USE_INSTALLOPTIONSEX

  !define UMUI_USE_ALTERNATE_PAGE
 ; !define UMUI_USE_UNALTERNATE_PAGE

;        !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
;          !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_LARGE

  !define UMUI_PAGEBGIMAGE
  !define UMUI_UNPAGEBGIMAGE

;--------------------------------
;Pages

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
 ; !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "License.rtf"
 ; !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS ;richtig?
 ; !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES


;    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "blabla.exe"
;   !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "run blabla"
;    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME "blabla.htm"
;    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_TEXT "blabla readme"
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK "Bla bla Website"
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK_LOCATION "/"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

    !define UMUI_ABORTPAGE_LINK "Bla bla"
    !define UMUI_ABORTPAGE_LINK_LOCATION "bla bla"
  !insertmacro UMUI_PAGE_ABORT


 ; !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
 ; !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
 ; !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK "bla bla bla"
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK_LOCATION "bla bla blab"
 ; !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

    !define UMUI_ABORTPAGE_LINK "bla bla bla"
    !define UMUI_ABORTPAGE_LINK_LOCATION "bla bla bla"
 ; !insertmacro UMUI_UNPAGE_ABORT

;--------------------------------
;Languages

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections

!include WinVer.nsh

;--------------------------------

Section "-Start" SEC00
    ;DetailPrint "Restart Information"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "Please ignore Restart Requests from the Windows Info Center. The System will be restarted at the End of the Installation."
 SectionEnd

Section "kalkules" SEC01
   SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\01_kalkules"
   SetOverwrite ifnewer
   File /r 01_kalkules\*.*
   ReadRegStr $WinEdition HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "ProductName"
   ${If} $WinEdition == "Windows 10 Pro"
         ExecWait "$INSTDIR\01_kalkules\setup_kalkules_1_11_1.exe"
         ${EndIf}
        
         ${Else}
         DetailPrint "kalkules not installed"
         ${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Section "-Finish" SEC03
    DetailPrint "Reboot request."
    MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "Installation is finished and Reboot is required. Do you wish to reboot the system?" IDNO +2
    ;Reboot
SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  Language strings
    LangString DESC_Sec01 ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Mirosoft Camera APP Installation via Side Loading. Windows 10 needs to be in Developer Mode during Installation."
    LangString DESC_Sec02 ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Finish Installation."

  Assign language strings to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
   !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Sec01} $(DESC_Sec01)
   !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Sec02} $(DESC_Sec02)
   !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Sec03} $(DESC_Sec03)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

;--------------------------------
```

I get the error when compiling.

Command line:
"C:\ProgramData\NSIS\makensis.exe"  /NOTIFYHWND 2363870  "E:\Develop\NSIS-WindowsCheck\Scorpion_Test.nsi"

Processing config: C:\ProgramData\NSIS\nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "E:\Develop\NSIS-WindowsCheck\Scorpion_Test.nsi" (ACP)
!insertmacro: macro "_If" requires 4 parameter(s), passed 2!
Error in script "E:\Develop\NSIS-WindowsCheck\Scorpion_Test.nsi" on line 110 -- aborting creation process

Hi everyone,

I dont get any further. I want to get something read from regedit and then do a simple if else loop. So if the Windows Editions product name contains that, it should be installed.I have also tried other variants that are written to a text file and then read, but unfortunately everything was unsuccessful.

Comment: The error line does not match the code you posted...

Comment: sorry my fault. This is the point where it doesn't go any further.

ReadRegStr $WinEdition HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "ProductName"

Comment: And where is $WinEdition declared?